# Restricting access if not coming from certain referer(s) PHP

Tags: php, restrict, referer

**I am racking my brain as to why this isn't working.**

What I would like to achieve, is to restrict access to a page on my own Website, only if coming from a certain website, Facebook for instance.

Since a link will be posted on 1 or more Facebook pages and/or my personal profile, would like the script to execute if coming from Facebook and/or any other "PAGES" it's posted on.

For instance, if I post my link on **www.facebook.com/This_is_my_PAGE** or is posted on my personal profile **www.facebook.com/freds_personal_profile** or someone shares my link on Facebook, would like the page accessible only to those coming from the Facebook domain.

I found the script below while searching for a solution, but it's echoing my error message, instead of redirecting to the link in question.

```
$target_site = 'https://www.facebook.com/';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && preg_match("/$target_site/",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
// do something with people from facebook.com
} 

else {
// do something else with everyone else

echo "Sorry, viewable to Facebook fans only.";

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should echo content of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in your error message. That would give you a hint.

Comment: HTTP_REFEER is not an obligatory header and it may not be set by the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your code is flawed because:

- What if the user is not using Facebook's "Secure version" (http rather than https)?
- What if the user is coming from `facebook.com` rather than `www.facebook.com`?
- What if a malicious user is tricking users into coming from a site like `http://example.com/evilpage.php?https://www.facebook.com/`?

The main reason it doesn't work is because your regex is completely invalid. Instead, it should be along the lines of:

```
preg_match("/".preg_quote($target_site,"/")."/i",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

([documentation on `preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg-quote))

Aside from all of this, there is no security in checking the referrer. It can be changed, it can e blocked altogether. It should not be relied on.

Comment: I took this from another similar question asked on SO, thought it would've held water. It was an accepted answer.

Comment: An answer being accepted means that the person asking the question found it to be correct. That doesn't mean it's the best answer nor that it's even right at all, just that it helped the most in the asker's opinion.

Comment: True Kolink. I will be more vigilant, if and when there's a next time.

Comment: I take it that using `.htaccess` would be a more secure method(?)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook hooks up external links to the `http` protocol, not `https`. Change your target site to this:

```
$target_site = 'http://www.facebook.com/';
```

You can confirm this by right-clicking a link posted in facebook and copying it to the clipboard (then pasting it). You'll see it looks like this:

```
`http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=...`
```

This is the case regardless of whether you are actually browsing with `https` or `http`.

Comment: I did try that Ben thanks, even with http and https and it's still showing my error message. That's what I don't get.

Comment: Fred, also I just noticed your regex is completely busted. See @Kilink's answer.

Comment: I'm working on his code now, getting a 500 error for some reason.

Comment: Update: Works! Kolink was right on the nose, and I appreciate your added input as well. the l.php?= was a nice touch. Cheers~